# Get field from table by giving field from another table (Room Library)

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am learning how to use Room in Android. I have two tables: KeyWordsTable (id, keyword) and CategoriesTable (id, imagePath). I want to do something like this:
user give a keyword -> checking which category it belongs to -> get imagePath from CategoriesTable.

I have @Dao interface and i did something like

`@Query("SElECT image_path AS imagePath FROM CategoriesTable JOIN KeywordsTable ON idKeyWords = idCategories WHERE category_name = :categoryName LIMIT 1")`

`CategoriesTable findImagePathByKeyWordName(String categoryName);`

Is it correct solution? Will I get imagePath by giving a keyword?

Thank you in advice :)

**CategoriesTable.class**

```
@Entity
public class CategoriesTable {
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int idCategories;

@ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
private String categoryName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "image_path")
private String imagePath;
//getters and setters
```

**KeywordsTable.class**

```
@Entity
public class KeywordsTable {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int idKeyWords;

@ColumnInfo(name = "keywords_name")
private String keywordsName;
//getters and setters
```

Comment: it might require a `LEFT JOIN` and possibly table names. and you cannot have both tables' PK with `autoGenerate = true` because the ids most likely won't match too well. a private key on one table has to be a foreign key on the other table... unless those tables are always 1:1 (but then one can already merge them into one table).

Comment: So i have to set foreign key but for which table? For KeywordsTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must provide foreign key on the `many` side of the relation. Moreover, you should set name of each table in their `@Entity` annotation.

**KeywordsTable.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "keywords",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = CategoriesTable.class,
                                  parentColumns = "idCategories",
                                  childColumns = "categoryId",
                                  onDelete = CASCADE))
public class KeywordsTable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int idKeyWords;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "keywords_name")
    private String keywordsName;

    private int categoryId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**CategoriesTable.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
public class CategoriesTable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int idCategories;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_path")
    private String imagePath;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Method in dao interface should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT image_path FROM categories INNER JOIN keywords" +
       "ON idCategories = categoryId WHERE keywords_name = :keyword LIMIT 1")
String findImagePathByKeyWordName(String keyword);
```